# if clause containing AND logic operator not working

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm building a bash script which have 2 conditions within an IF statement, linked by an AND logic operator, but it complains when executing.
Just for the record, if I run each condition in it's unique IF, both works just fine. Problem arises when I try to execute both glued by the -a (AND) operator. Here it is:

```
if [[ "$1" =~ ".com" -a test "$#" -eq 1 ]]
then
echo "olalá"
fi
```

I'll appreciate any tip on this issue.

Comment: You don't need that `test` command there; you're already in the middle of a boolean expression. `if  [[ "$1" =~ ".com" -a  "$#" -eq 1 ]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-a` is the AND operator in a `[ ]` test expression, but `[[ ]]` conditional expressions use `&&` instead. Also, there is a stray `test` in the expression that doesn't belong there at all. Here's the corrected version:

```
if [[ "$1" =~ ".com" && "$#" -eq 1 ]]
```

You could equivalently use two separate `[[ ]]` expressions and use `&&` between them:

```
if [[ "$1" =~ ".com" ]] && [[ "$#" -eq 1 ]]
```

(If you were using `[ ]` expressions, this would be the preferred method because of ambiguities in the syntax involving `-a`, `-o`, and such; but with `[[ ]]`, there's no ambiguity and either method works fine.)